# wufoo get xml entries

Tags: xml, api, get, feed, wufoo

I'd like to get the entries (feed) from a form I have with wufoo in xml format. If I use reports to pull the data... all I get is txt, csv, xls. (XLS is not working with the cms I'm using.) If I use the wufoo api get request it prompts for a username and password which doesn't work since I want the cms to pull in the data dynamically. Is there anyway I can pass the username and password through the url with the api... or anyway around not having a username and password... or something else. I'm not wanting to post data... just pulling the records from the wufoo db.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

you can pull xml data from Wufoo, including reports, using the API.  Check out the [reports API](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/reports/).  You pass through your Wufoo API Key instead of username/password.  You may even do so though the URL itself, like so:

```
https://{apiKey}:x@{subdomain}.wufoo.com/api/v3/reports/{reportIdentifier}.{xml|json}
```

But, including your API key is considered a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643355/https-url-with-token-parameter-how-secure-is-it), so be sure you want to expose your credentials in that way.  The best way to do this is through a POST.

Comment: since I'm pulling into a push cms and republishing the xml, i don't mind using a url with the api key since it won't be exposed. Is there anyway to generate a url, like above, with a security token in it?

Comment: the {apiKey} variable is a wufoo security token, which we call an API key.  Read about it here: http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/#key

Comment: problem with this method is that the cms that is pulling the feed thinks that it is a possible phishing site and won't grab it.

Comment: If the CMS won't allow it, then you're out of luck.  If you have access to some server-side stuff, you can use curl, but I'm going to bet that you have restricted access to the back end.