# how to download file using api angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I have an API that downloads a file, I have a button on the button I have a click that sends a request to the API for download a file, but it doesn't work request sending successfully but the file is not downloaded, but when I'm adding the URL into the browser the file is successfully downloaded

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="exportFile()">Download</button>
```

**TS**

```
  exportFile(): void{
this.companiesService.export().subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
}
```

**Service**

```
  export(){
    const headers = this.httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.cookieService.get('access-token')}`);
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/company/export/`,{headers});
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43133108/5319180 I think this will solve your issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle file downloads with JWT based authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452031/how-to-handle-file-downloads-with-jwt-based-authentication)

Comment: @D.B.K Thanks, but I tried, this version doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process the returned blob and save it as a file. Just returning it is not enough. Perhaps this demo can give you more insight how to improve your service. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-download-progress-qsqsnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdownload.ts