# AngularJS $http POST request with JSON parameter AND query string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, http

As the title suggests, I am attempting to write an AJAX call using Angular's $http object. I would like to send a post request that submits JSON in the body of the request, but also has a query string appended to the URL. After reading the documentation for $http all the way through, surfing for answers on SO, and attempting several different configurations, *I am still not clear on how to pass the parameters correctly.* Currently, my API responds with either empty JSON or Bad Request (400).

**Code**

```
function inviteStaff (json) {
    authToken = service.getAuthToken();
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: baseUrl + '/invitations' + '?authToken=' + authToken,
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}
```

**Consuming Function**

```
self.invite = function ($form) {
    self.showLoader = true;
    InvitesService.inviteStaff($scope.inviteModel).then(function () {
        $form.$setPristine();
        $scope.inviteModel.timestamp = new Date();
        $scope.invites.unshift($scope.inviteModel);
        $scope.inviteModel = self.createNewInvite();
        self.showLoader = false;
    }, 
    function () {
       self.showLoader = false;
    });
};
```

**Request log**

```
data: "authToken=********&t=*****" // this is weird because it adds another "t" parameter to this query string here 
headers: Object
    Accept: "application/json"
    Accept-Language: "en"
    Content-type: "application/json"
    authToken: "*********" // just the token here
    __proto__: Object
method: "POST"
params: Object
timeout: Object
transformRequest: Array[1]
transformResponse: Array[1]
url: "http://****.****.com:****/doctors/invitations?authToken=*****"
__proto__: Object
```

**Param JSON object**

```
{
    accountType: "LEAD_DOCTOR", 
    firstName: "kraken", 
    lastName: "lastName", 
    email: "kraken@mail.com"
}
```

Can anyone shed a little light on how this should work? Do I pass the json object to data or params? Do I need to use JSON.stringify on the data field? In some cases, I also saw people passing an empty string to data.

I also have been running it through Charles Proxy. I can get very close to what I want, but for some reason the JSON is showing under the JSON Text filter as a query string, and not the JSON filter.

Any ideas would be helpful. I will be refactoring and upgrading it all to use the $resource tool, but we are on a tight deadline and I just want to get this working for now. Let me know if you need more info.

**UPDATE**
We're using swagger to document our API, and you can actually hit the endpoint in their UI. It produces the following CURL command. I thought it might help spot the issue.

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
    \"firstName\": \"string\",
    \"lastName\": \"string\",
    \"email\": \"blah@mail.com\",
    \"accountType\": \"CLIENT\"
}" "http://*****.****.com:****/doctors/invitations?authToken=***obfuscatedAuthToken***"
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Second question: you can pass the whole javascript object, Angular will handle it

Comment: @MB I will update the question

Comment: using data is correct, params is used for variables and data for an object. You do not have to do anything to your object just pass it as is

Comment: where are you passing it to? could be you are accepting it wrong on the API side?

Comment: Check the latest update @MB. I get successful response in both swagger and on Advanced REST Client for Chrome.

Comment: I'm confused. What URL are you having problems with? You're showing code that posts to an invitations URL, but you're showing the response from a login URL. Which is it?

Comment: @Brett You are correct! Sorry I was messing with two at once. I updated the log and the json obj

Comment: This might seem silly as http headers are supposed to be case-insensitive, but have you tried `Content-Type` instead of `Content-type`?

Comment: I tried it just now. No dice. :(

Comment: It would be interesting to find out where that extra `t` parameter in the query string is coming from.

Comment: @Brett I looked into it. There is an additional JS file that consumes this. It adds an additional parameter. I'm trying to see if there is anything I should add here.

Comment: It's a timestamp @Brett. I stepped into the consuming code, and nothing much happens there since the request fails.

Comment: @Brett I added that function above

Comment: I found an httpInterceptor function that appears to be breaking the JSON, since previously we were not using JSON. I think I can get to the bottom of this. Thanks for helping me refine my $http request, y'all. I'll post the solution later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out we had an HTTP Interceptor function elsewhere in the codebase that was changing the content-type! Wrapped that in a conditional, and it is good to go now. Thanks to everyone who helped me ensure my code was written correctly!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take advantage of the header field:

```
function inviteStaff (json) {
authToken = service.getAuthToken();
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + '/invitations',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'authToken': authToken
    }
   });
 }
```

Then on the server side, ask the current request for the header value of authToken.

Passing Tokens in the URL has some security concerns, for your reading: [https URL with token parameter : how secure is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643355/https-url-with-token-parameter-how-secure-is-it)

Comment: "we are on a tight deadline and I just want to get this working for now" -- Your suggestion is valid, but not what the OP is looking for atm.

Comment: @Brett was right on the nose. Very helpful advice for the future, though. Thanks! We are actually already planning to tighten up security in the near future.