# (Browser Side) how to prevent IDM(internet download manager) from trying to download auth protected files

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, download, idm

we have a web app in production, one of our services includes paid files.
which after purchasing, user is able to download them . so obviously download needs an authenticated user.

but IDM(internet download manager) tries to download the file , asking a password from user.

we don't want to ask our users to change their IDM settings . and we don't want our download to get interrupted by IDM.
what can be done with js and html in this situation? any tricks?

thank you.

Comment: You should not care what download manager users use.

Comment: @Ram yes but our users are not happy with it. in my country most people use IDM. but they may not know how to solve it and they think it's a bug .

Comment: I don't know what authentication system you are using but one thing you can do is generating access tokens for downloads. This question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753021/how-can-i-pass-an-auth-token-when-downloading-a-file

Comment: More helpful question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452031/how-to-handle-file-downloads-with-jwt-based-authentication